# How do I get a slice of a Vec<T> in Rust?

Tags: vector, rust

I can not find within the documentation of `Vec<T>` how to retrieve a slice from  a specified range.

Is there something like this in the standard library:

```
let a = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
let suba = a.subvector(0, 2); // Contains [1, 2];
```

Answer (score 237, accepted):

The documentation for `Vec` covers this in [the section titled "slicing"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#slicing).

You can create a [`slice`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html) of a [`Vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html) or [`array`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html) by indexing it with a [`Range`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.Range.html) (or [`RangeInclusive`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.RangeInclusive.html), [`RangeFrom`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.RangeFrom.html), [`RangeTo`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.RangeTo.html), [`RangeToInclusive`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.RangeToInclusive.html), or [`RangeFull`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.RangeFull.html)), [for example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=712605c97fe6060f8d299f6e94d3bcb9):

```
fn main() {
    let a = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    // With a start and an end
    println!("{:?}", &a[1..4]);

    // With a start and an end, inclusive
    println!("{:?}", &a[1..=3]);

    // With just a start
    println!("{:?}", &a[2..]);

    // With just an end
    println!("{:?}", &a[..3]);

    // With just an end, inclusive
    println!("{:?}", &a[..=2]);

    // All elements
    println!("{:?}", &a[..]);
}
```

Comment: What's the behavior of the range with no explicit end index? Does it imply the range goes to the end of the vector (e.g. vector length)? I can't find this documented.

Comment: Yes, that's right. It's explicitly documented in the docs for the `SliceIndex` impls, for example, [`impl SliceIndex<str> for RangeFrom<usize>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.RangeFrom.html#impl-SliceIndex%3Cstr%3E):

"Returns a slice of the given string from the byte range `[begin, len)`. Equivalent to `&self[begin .. len]` or `&mut self[begin .. len]`."

Answer (score 52):

If you wish to convert the entire `Vec` to a slice, you can use *[deref coercion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-02-deref.html#implicit-deref-coercions-with-functions-and-methods)*:

```
fn main() {
    let a = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    let b: &[i32] = &a;

    println!("{:?}", b);
}
```

This coercion is automatically applied when calling a function:

```
fn print_it(b: &[i32]) {
    println!("{:?}", b);
}

fn main() {
    let a = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    print_it(&a);
}
```

You can also call [`Vec::as_slice`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.as_slice), but it's a bit less common:

```
fn main() {
    let a = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    let b = a.as_slice();
    println!("{:?}", b);
}
```

See also:

- [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec), or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/155423)

Comment: +1 I like `.as_slice()` much better than `[..]` because it conveys the intent. (Converting the Vec into a slice because only slices, not Vecs, implement `io::Read`.)