# Can a slice pattern be used to parse command line arguments without cloning?

Tags: rust

Can the [slice pattern in Rust](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/edition-guide/rust-2018/slice-patterns.html) be used to parse command line arguments?

I capture the arguments as: `let args: Vec<String> = std::env::args().skip(1).collect();`

I'm thinking something like this, which doesn't compile:

```
// example usage: progname run bash ls -la
match args {
    ["run", rest_of_commands[..]] => println!("{:?}", rest_of_commands),
    _ => println!("usage: run <your-command>"),
}
```

Comment: I think [`Vec::get`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.get) will do what you want.

Comment: Please define what **efficiently** means to you in this case. Asking "do I want to explore" is about as opinion-based as a question could be. Opinion-based questions are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Shepmaster I'm learning the language and wanted to avoid `.clone()` that I've gotten used to in some of these cases. You're right 'Do I want...' sound like an opinion but it was an edit to the original question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Rust 1.42, you can do the following:

```
fn main() {
    let args = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];
    match args {
        ["run", rest_of_commands @ ..] => println!("{:?}", rest_of_commands),
        _ => println!("usage: run <your-command>"),
    }
}
```

([Permalink to the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=417a8869da358af731e219e09e9b48dd))

The syntax `..` means "the rest", while `_name_ @ _pattern_` binds the matched value to the given name.

Comment: thanks for the answer! However, do you have a way to do the conversion from `Vec<String>` returned by `std::env::args().collect()` to an array of `&str` (as in your, and my examples)?

Comment: @sysarcher [How to match a String against string literals in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25383488/155423); [How do I get a slice of a Vec<T> in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39785597/155423); [Convert Vec<String> to Vec<&str>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33216514/155423).

Comment: Stable since 1.42 (Mar'20) https://blog.rust-lang.org/inside-rust/2020/03/04/recent-future-pattern-matching-improvements.html - the feature line no longer needed.