# How to get a reference to an array inside another array in Rust?

Tags: arrays, rust, slice

I have something like this:

```
let test_data: [u8; 6] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

How can I get a `&[u8; 3]` pointing to the first three elements?

I know I can do `test_data[0 .. 3]`, but that returns a slice `[u8]`. I'd also rather not convert the slice to an array if possible because I'm doing this with a ton of arrays and it needs to be as efficient as possible.

I'm doing this so that I can parse information from a byte array, so if there's an easier way to do that than splitting the array up, I'm also interested in that.

Comment: `let piece: &[u8; 3] = test_data[0..3].try_into().unwrap()`

Comment: My "challenge your assumptions" follow up would be: *why do you require an array reference (`&[u8; 3]`) instead of just accepting a slice (`&[u8]`)?*

Comment: Well, I need a [u8; 8] for u64::from_be_bytes @Shepmaster. I guess the .try_into().unwrap() method is probably fast enough.

Comment: You may also want to look at [How can I convert a buffer of a slice of bytes (&\[u8\]) to an integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29307474/155423).

Comment: *probably fast enough* — yes, depending on exactly what you start with, that will be a free transformation (the panic from `unwrap` can even be removed in certain cases).

Comment: thanks for the help!