# How to convert a 4 element &[u8] into i32?

Tags: rust, unsafe

I have an `i32` that i pass to my keyvalue database.

```rs
let a = 1234i32;
db.put(&a.to_be_bytes());
```

But i get it back as `&[u8]`, how to convert it back to `i32`?

---

update: this example pretty much does what i want.

```
use std::convert::TryInto;

fn read_be_i32(input: &[u8]) -> i32 {
    i32::from_be_bytes(input.try_into().unwrap())
}
```

Comment: Since you already know about [`i32::to_be_bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html#method.to_be_bytes), why not use [`i32::from_be_bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html#method.from_be_bytes)?

Comment: Duplicate: [How can I convert a buffer of a slice of bytes (&\[u8\]) to an integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29307474/how-can-i-convert-a-buffer-of-a-slice-of-bytes-u8-to-an-integer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`i32::from_be_bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u32.html#method.from_be_bytes) and from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50080940/1695172), `TryFrom`:

```rust
use std::convert::TryFrom;
fn main() {
    let a = 1234i32.to_be_bytes();
    let a_ref: &[u8] = &a;
    let b = i32::from_be_bytes(<[u8; 4]>::try_from(a_ref).expect("Ups, I did it again..."));
    println!("{}", b);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9f4d4c1e76370d50e1e0722538ee4beb)