# What would be the Rust equivalent to charCodeAt from Nodejs?

Tags: rust

I am wondering what would be the equivalent to nodeJS `charCodeAt` in Rust? I have tried digging into the Rust documentation but I have not gotten very far.

However here is where I got so far - it might be not as useful, I do appreciate directions.

#### Rust

```rust
fn main() {
    let v1 = "\0\u{1e}2022-Dec-2 11:42:16-0800\0";

    println!("{:?}", v1.chars().nth(01));
}
```

```js
let ReadShort = function (v, p) {
    return (v.charCodeAt(p) << 8) + v.charCodeAt(p + 1);
};

let v1 = "\0\u{1e}2022-Dec-2 11:42:16-0800\0";

console.log(ReadShort(v1, 0) == 30); // expected result true
```

Comment: Can you explain for those who don't know Node what you expect the Rust code to do?

Comment: The charCodeAt() method returns an integer between 0 and 65535 representing the UTF-16 code unit at the given index.
I was expecting to get the integer value, i was able to select the portion charachters that has the wanted value, but did not know how tp parse it.

Comment: If you are willing to accept the UTF-8 code unit at the nth pos, maybe because your string is mostly ASCII you can do `v1.as_bytes()[n]`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert a buffer of a slice of bytes (&\[u8\]) to an integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29307474/how-can-i-convert-a-buffer-of-a-slice-of-bytes-u8-to-an-integer)

Comment: It looks like you're parsing a binary format, and you want to parse the first two bytes as a big-endian 16-bit integer. In that case, I would suggest against treating this binary message as a string. Please see whether my suggested question helps.

Comment: @justinas Can not change the current structure of the code. The binary will be part of the string at different indexes. The accepted answer here solves the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "character code" is just the underlying bytes of the character, also known as the Unicode code point. You can get it by a simple conversion to an integer:

```
fn main() {
    let v1 = "\0\u{1e}2022-Dec-2 11:42:16-0800\0";
    let character = v1.chars().nth(1).unwrap();
    let code = u32::from(character);
    println!("{}", code);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the parsing part is what i was missing.
I guise there is no need to implement the  `ReadShort` function, using rust-lang `left-shift`, right?

Comment: @7skies I'm afraid I don't know what you are referring to there.