# How do I specify the calling convention for a C callback that uses &mut [u8] and u32?

Tags: rust, ffi, calling-convention

I have a crate that holds a function pointer (defined in C), and calls some predefined arguments. I suspect that I cannot get the call to comply with the C calling convention. I have reviewed [the relevant Rust docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/ffi.html#foreign-calling-conventions), and believe that I am specifying the calling convention where appropriate...

A simple example to illustrate:

The Rust crate with a simple struct containing a buffer and function pointer to pack it:

```
pub type Callback = extern "C" fn(buffer: &mut [u8], current_index: u32, max_index: u32) -> u32;
const BUFFER_SIZE: usize = 32_767;
pub type DataBuffer = [u8; BUFFER_SIZE];

#[no_mangle]
pub struct Foo {
    buffer: DataBuffer,
    pub current_index: u32,
    callback: Option<Callback>,
}

impl Foo {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Foo {
            current_index: 0,
            buffer: [0u8; BUFFER_SIZE],
            callback: None,
        }
    }
    fn add_callback(&mut self, callback: Callback) {
        self.callback = Some(callback);
    }

    fn call_callback(&mut self) {
        let increment = self.callback.expect("")(
            self.buffer
                .get_mut(self.current_index as usize..)
                .expect(""),
            self.current_index,
            BUFFER_SIZE as u32,
        );
        self.current_index += increment;
    }
}
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn FooNew() -> Box<Foo> {
    Box::new(Foo::new())
}
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn FooAddCallback(foo: &mut Foo, callback: Callback) {
    foo.add_callback(callback);
}
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn FooCallCallback(foo: &mut Foo) {
    foo.call_callback();
}
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn FooPrint(foo: &mut Foo) {
    for c in foo.buffer.iter() {
        print!("{}", *c as char);
    }
    println!("\n");
}
```

and some corresponding C code to call it:

```c
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Foo Foo;

extern Foo* FooNew();
extern void FooAddCallback(Foo* foo, void* callback);
extern void FooCallCallback(Foo* foo);
extern void FooPrint(Foo* foo);

unsigned int getHeaders(char* buffer, unsigned int current_index, unsigned int max_index)
{
    if (current_index > max_index)
    {
        printf("\nError current_index(%d) > max_index(%d) !!\nThis is most likely a C-api byte order problem\n", current_index, max_index);
        exit(-1);
    }
    strcpy(buffer, "~HEADER~\0");

    return 9;
}

int main()
{
    Foo* foo = FooNew();
    FooAddCallback(foo, getHeaders);
    FooCallCallback(foo);
    FooCallCallback(foo);
    FooCallCallback(foo);

    FooPrint(foo);

    return 0;
}
```

When run, the second two arguments to the callback get passed incorrectly (i.e. the parameter for `current_index` gets passed to `max_index` and vice-versa, in the example above its passing 0 to `max_index` and 32767 to `current_index`). Reversing the order of these args(seemingly making the calling order read incorrect) causes it to execute correctly...

I suspect I am just calling the callback wrong, or need to specify the calling convention differently.

Ah right, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27150652/155423) was mentioned. This is the direct inverse of their question, but the ethos is the same. *Arrays/Slices cannot be directly passed via the FFI*.

Comment: `extern "C"` — that's the calling convention; there's no other "configuration" for it.

Comment: *`&mut [u8]`* — this is **not** a type that can be passed to C. C has no concept of slices. See [*The Rust FFI Omnibus* - Rust functions with slice arguments](http://jakegoulding.com/rust-ffi-omnibus/slice_arguments/).

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [How can I get an array or a slice from a raw pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27150652/155423). If you disagree, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.