# Cast multidimensional array to slice

Tags: arrays, rust

In Rust, I have a square, multidimensional array with a const generic size:

```rust
fn generate_array<const N: usize>() -> [[u32; N]; N] {
    // ...
}
```

I want to pass this array to a library that takes a one-dimensional array:

```rust
fn library_function(width: usize, height: usize, data: &[u32]);
```

My array doesn't coerce to `&[u32]` so I can't just pass a reference. I know this *should* be a trivial conversion, but I couldn't find an idiomatic way of doing it. From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27150865/7487237), I created a function to construct the slice from a raw pointer, but I am not sure if there are certain types where this is invalid.

```rust
const fn as_flat_slice<const N: usize, T>(arr: &[[T; N]; N]) -> &[T] {
    unsafe {
        std::slice::from_raw_parts(arr.as_ptr() as *const _, N * N)
    }
}
```

([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d9daed8223745497edf91a89eaf3ae35))

Is there a non-`unsafe` way to quickly perform this conversion?

Comment: [`slice::flatten`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.flatten)? (currently unstable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On nightly, there is [`<[T]>::flatten()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.flatten).

On stable, there is nothing in the standard library, although there is crates [e.g. [`slice-of-array`](https://docs.rs/slice-of-array/latest/slice_of_array/trait.SliceFlatExt.html#tymethod.flat)).

Anyhow, your code is sound.